# How to screen cast automation testing process in ipad

Tags: ios, selenium, automation, appium

I am able to screen cast web browser automation using java and selenium,
but I am unable to screen cast the automation testing process in ios and android mobile application.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

We use Cucumber with Ruby and appium for ios automation and take screenshots of the app before and after scenarios using hooks. Not what you were looking for I know but it is an option.